# how to create California in the DNN list in NB_Store country list

Tags: dotnetnuke

hi
I want to know "how to create California  in the DNN list  in NB_Store country list?" This is for implementing tax to California state Only. In order to do this i have created txapplies.list and put CA. But i can't get the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, because my test DNN deployment is busy, but I think adding a relevant entry to the List table will do the trick.

Here is SQL that retrieves countries from the Lists table:

```
select listname,value,text,parentid from lists where listname = 'Country'
```

Queue that up in SSMS, and try adding a country manually

Keep in mind, DNN utilizes heavy caching by default -- you may need to disable caching in your host settings for this test.